# How does Linux hide file for duration of mount?

Tags: linux, mount

In Linux, internally, all files have a file path, which are represented by a chain of dentries and inodes. When a file system is mounted, its mount point is given by a file path, and the original file at the mount point becomes inaccessible. When the file system is unmounted, the original file becomes accessible again. So, at mount time, something must happen to the dentry of the original file. I imagine that there’s a stack of dentries at each file path and that mount and unmount stack and unstack dentries, but I don’t see evidence of that in the code.

In terms of structures like dentry, vfsmount etc. how does Linux hide the original file just for the duration of the mount?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand how this works. The key is to understand that mount affects path traversals and not already opened files.

Before the mount, opening file /tmp/a results in a path traversal and a struct file. The path traversal starts from the root vfsmount’s / dentry, proceeds to the /tmp dentry and then to the /tmp/a dentry, The struct file’s path points to the root vfsmount and the /tmp/a dentry, and its inodes point to the file’s contents.

During the mount of a filesystem on /tmp/a, the system registers the (root vfsmount, /tmp/a dentry) pair in a hash table of mountpoints, updates the /tmp/a dentry as a mountpoint by setting a flag, and adds a new vfsmount as a child of the root vfsmount. The new vfsmount points to two dentries: the /tmp/a dentry through its mountpoint member and to its own / dentry through its root member.

After the mount, opening /tmp/a results in a path traversal and a file struct, like before. But now when the path traversal reaches the /tmp/a dentry it detects the mount flag, looks up the vfsmount of the mounted file system in the hash table and “jumps” to its / dentry.
The struct file’s path points to the mounted vfsmount and its / dentry, and this dentry’s inodes point to the file’s contents.

File operations like read and write on the struct file opened before the mount continue to work as if nothing happened because the struct file has a pointer to the /tmp/a dentry of the root vfsmount, and the inodes of the dentry were not changed by mount. But any new path traversals through /tmp/a will jump into another dentry of another vfsmount, so the original /tmp/a dentry will not be returned, so it becomes hidden until unmount.

One thing I realized is the a path traversal is represented by a chain of vfsmount/dentry pairs and a path by a specific vfsmount/dentry pair.